# Cannot find function

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am using sencha architect. i added a function in app.js to call it inside an event listener of a view. Adding it manually by editing **app.js** file like:

```
function a(){

}
```

works as expected.

The problem is that if I add it by using architect resulting in:

```
a:function{

}
```

inside **app.js**, calling function in the event listener results in `can't find variable` error.
Do you have a clue why this is happening? I would like to add it by architect since whenever I add a new view f.e the **app.js** is overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, in order to call it right it should be:
NameOftheApp.app.a()

Answer (score 0):

I use this way:

app.js:

`setUrl: function(newUrl)`

call:

`this.getApplication().setUrl("Menu");`